# How to add tables in asp.net core Identity

Tags: c#, database, sqlite, asp.net-identity, asp.net-core-identity

I created asp.net core project with Authentication -> individual user accounts. I created all the roles and authorised their pages. It is working but i had to uprage the project, adding two more tables. The first table is connected with the second. And the second must be connected with the scaffolded user table. I tried making the relations with OnModelcreating in DbContext but it doesn’t work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to your description, if you want to modify the identity table, I suggest you could refer to below steps:

1.Add the new model:
e.g:

```
public class NewTestModel
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    // This is used to make one to one relationship to identity user
    public IdentityUser user { get; set; }
}
```

2.Modify the dbcontext:

```
public class ApplicationDbContext : IdentityDbContext
{
    public ApplicationDbContext(DbContextOptions<ApplicationDbContext> options)
        : base(options)
    {
    }


    public DbSet<NewTestModel> newTestModels { get; set; }
        

}
```

3.Open the package management console and run below codes:

```
Add-Migration Modify1


update-database
```

[image]

Result:

[image]